# creating an horizontal scrollview inside a horizontal scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a horizontal scroll view inside horizontal scroll view in android. First horizontal scrolling views are working fine. When i am trying to scroll second horizontal scrolling views are not working.

my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="1"></Button>
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="2"></Button>
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="3"></Button>
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="4"></Button>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </HorizontalScrollView>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

can anybody share your knowledge how to achieve this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom class for nested scroll view for support horizontal smooth scroll.

```
public class HorizontalNestedScrollView extends NestedScrollView {
private int slop;
private float mInitialMotionX;
private float mInitialMotionY;

public HorizontalNestedScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
    slop = config.getScaledEdgeSlop();
}

public HorizontalNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public HorizontalNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}


private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
            lastX = ev.getX();
            lastY = ev.getY();

            // This is very important line that fixes 
           computeScroll();


            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float curX = ev.getX();
            final float curY = ev.getY();
            xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
            yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
            lastX = curX;
            lastY = curY;

            if (xDistance > yDistance) {
                return false;
            }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
}
```

You can read about the issue and the simple fix here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194398

Use this class in place of your nestedscrollview in the xml file, and the child lists should intercept and handle the touch events properly.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: you can replace HorizontalScrollView with HorizontalNestedScrollView in your xml file.

Comment: Create package( exp utils ) then add this class in this package folder.

for exp com.example.utils.HorizontalNestedScrollView 

`<com.example.utils.HorizontalNestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

</com.example.utils.HorizontalNestedScrollView>`

Comment: got it. where have to use first scroll view or second scroll view

Comment: First scroll view

Comment: I tried as per guidelines its working fine. When we use first scroll view.But i want to make it as a both scrollable

Comment: Please try following in inner(second scroll view)

`innerScroll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (youredittext.hasFocus()) {
               v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
               switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                      v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                      return true;
                }
             }
             return false;
       }
}); `